# Transfer of foreigner's US real estate to US citizen child

Tags: united-states, real-estate, gift-tax

What would be the best way to transfer real estate (100% owned and paid for; no mortgage or debts) by a non-US citizen and non US resident to his child that is US citizen and living in the US from a tax perspective?

Comment: How much is the property worth, roughly?

Comment: From the original purchase price or from the fair market value (e.g now) ?

Comment: Both, but more interested in fair market value.

Comment: ~700K for the fair market value and 390K for the original purchase price

Comment: How old is the child?

Comment: Child is an adult (above 30years)

Comment: An important question to ask is: where is the property located? Is it in the US or elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

There are three options:

1. Non-resident sells to the resident - no complications there, as long as it is an arms-length transaction (i.e.: market price). Recipient has his own basis (same as stepped up basis in #3).
2. Non-resident gifts to the resident (or sells at a discount, which is a gift) - then a gift tax is in order. There's the $14K exemption, but no lifetime exemption, so essentially gift tax will be paid. Recipient keeps the basis.
3. Non-resident leaves as inheritance to the resident on death - there's $65K exclusion (IIRC, numbers change each year) and estate taxes will be paid. Recipient gets a stepped-up basis.

More details [here](http://www.sgrlaw.com/resources/newsletters/trusts_estates_trends/trustsnestatestrends_winter11/1622/) (amounts are a bit outdated in the article).

Ignoring other considerations, investing in having your foreigner parent become US resident may save you quite a lot in taxes.

Comment: Thanks for all of the clarification, seems like #2 seems preferable, but how much would be the gift tax (roughly) based on the home value listed above ?

Comment: @user3716806 I believe the top gift tax rate is 40%, same as estate tax. That would make #3 actually better, if you're willing to wait (exemption is larger).